# External Sharing for SharePoint Vs External Sharing for Office 365 groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, external-users, office-365-groups, external-sharing

Now to manage external sharing for SharePoint sites, i have the "Sharing" link inside the SharePoint admin center, as follow:-

[image]

I also have the sharing per site collection, as follow:-
[image]

Now our customer has added 5 office 365 groups, which will have sharepoint sites. but those sites are not listed inside the above sharepoint sites list. **and my question is how we can manage the External sharing for these office 365 groups' sites?**. now i find this link which talks about external sharing for office 365 (which seems that it works a bit different from sharepoint external sharing) https://sharepointmaven.com/office-365-groups-external-sharing-works/ . But after reading this link i got confused, as when i went to "tenant admin site">>"Settings">>"Security & Privacy">>"Sharing">>click on Edit, i got this popup:-
[image]

and from there i have the option so set external sharing for sharepoint.. and i got different options than the ones i have inside the sharepoint central admin site.. so are the sharepoint external options inside the "Security & Privacy", is only for the office 365 groups' sharepoint sites? if the answer is yes, then why i only have one "site settings" rather than 5 which represents our 5 Office 365 groups' sites?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is an option. This blogpost might be helpfull. https://peteskelly.com/enable-external-sharing-for-office-365-group-site-collections/

The other option is the new admin centre. You can view all site collections and manage sharing from there:

[image: External Sharing]

Comment: but my question is about how  the current setting works? mainly are the external sharing settings for sharepoint sites (from "admin central site>>sharepoint>>sharing") apply also to office 365 groups' sites? if the answer is yes,, then what is the purpose of the settings inside "tenant admin site">>"Settings">>"Security & Privacy">>"Sharing" ???

Comment: There are two things: You can add external guests to groups (and teams) as a member and thus sharing the whol iste. I think that setting is controled from Security & Privacy. However you can also set sharing for the sites only and share e.g. just a document or library. That more granular setting is controlled from the SharePoint admin interface. Does that make sense?

Comment: sorry i did not get your point. also I tried the newer admin center interface, now from there i can see the group 365 sites (not just the sharepoint site as in the old interface),,, but i do not have any option to set the sharing for the office 365 sites inside the newer interface... i am not sure why Microsoft is complicating everything.. they provide newer interface which have less options compared to previous interface!!!.. is this correct? or i am missing something?

Comment: I've checked in a first release tenant, maybe that's a reason why I have the option. However please select a group site collection -> info button in the top right and the option is at the bottom. It's a bit hidden.

Comment: Ok now i click on a sharepoint site and on an office 365 site inside the new interface for the admin center site, where i got a section named "Sharing status",, and the options i got inside this section (even for the sharepoint sites) are totally different from the sharing options inside the classic interface for the admin center site... so i am totally confused on what is Microsoft trying to deliver... have you check the sharing options inside the new interface and inside the previous interface?? looks like these settings are for different things!!